# Setting initial value of knockout viewmodel using razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, knockout.js

I'm finding it strange that I can't find any information about how to populate the Knockout viewmodel dynamically. I guess my search terms are incorrect or something.

Anyways as I'm using Asp.Net MVC 3 and am only going to use knockout for one specific page this first time I was hoping I could somehow use the Razor model to insert into the knockout.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.PropertyName, new { data_bind = "value: name" })
```

I figured that this didn't work because even if the razor populates the field with the PropertyName it happens before the binding so it doesn't force it's value to the knockout viewmodel.

```
        var viewModel = {
        name: ko.observable(@GetPoertyNameUsingRazorSomehow)
    };
```

This doesn't work either, at least not in anyway I understand.

As we can easily get RazorModel data using MVC 3 normally I was sure we somehow could inject it into the Knockout viewModel. I haven't seen any tutorials that explain how. What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I created a little library on top of Json.NET for just such an occasion:

https://github.com/paultyng/FluentJson.NET

You can create JSON in a Razor view like this (note the Knockout extension methods):

```
@JsonObject.Create()
    .AddProperty("name", "value")
    .AddProperty("childObject", c => {
        .AddProperty("childProperty", "value2")
    })
    .AddObservable("knockoutProperty", 123)
```

This would produce JSON similar to this:

```
{"name":"value","childObject":{"childProperty":"value2"},"knockoutProperty":ko.observable(123)}
```

The Knockout methods are added via extension methods and other things can easily extend as well.

The package is on Nu-Get if you want it.

Comment: Very nice, I'm new to all this so I do not know JSON. Is that the default Javascript object? Also does it handle properties that are collections of other objects? Also, what is the Nu-Get command?

Comment: PM> Install-Package fluentjson.net

Comment: There is an `AddObservableArray` method as well

Comment: I'm currently extending it to just allow you to do `@Knockout.ToViewModel(Model)` and it will enumerable the model properties, to simplify some of my own code where its just straight MVC Model to Knockout Model serialization and I don't want to have to call mapping on the client.

Comment: Yeah I was kinda expecting someone to do a HtmlHelper extension `@Html.ViewModelFor(Model)` and then also for the fields `@Html.ValueBoundFOr(m => m.Name)`

Comment: You can get close by doing:  `ko.mapping.fromJS(@Json.Encode(Model))` assuming you are also referencing the mapping plugin to knockout.

Comment: So this Json.Net is that a library and does I guess it comes along with fluentjson in nuget?

Comment: It should come along, its a much more comprehensive JSON serialization library, you can find more about it here: http://json.codeplex.com/ The built in serialization doesn't really handle custom object construction (like `ko.observable` or `Date`) so built on top of something else.

Comment: How would you add a collection of childobjects to a ObservableArray using FluenJson ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your property name should be a string, this should work if you enclose @GetPoertyNameUsingRazorSomehow in quotes. Otherwise, you're passing an undefined object into the observable.

```
name: ko.observable('@GetPoertyNameUsingRazorSomehow')
```

Comment: Are you sure, seems like Razor syntax doesn't work inside the Script tag.

Comment: Intellisense won't work in the script tag I don't beleive, but the output should work.

Comment: Nice. Is this something that is often used to populate viewModels or can you point me to a guide that explains that?

Comment: I think in terms of standard use of knockout many people will instead use the `fromJS` or `fromJSON` mapping methods and pull data from the server via ajax calls instead of sending it down hardcoded in to the view.  Or just use json serialization in your view from your model, so you aren't manually writing out all the properties necessarily.

Comment: I have tried this in MVC3 and MVC4 and intellisense work in script tag placed in script section. Check your web.config in views folder to make sure it is referencing appropriate stuff